# Android Studio 3.1 gives error: ComputableLiveData.getLiveData can only be called from within the same library group

Tags: android

After I upgraded Android Studio 3.1 to AI-173.4670197, 
I am getting this error on .getLiveData() line.

Error description is:

```
*ComputableLiveData.getLiveData can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=android.arch.lifecycle)
This API has been flagged with a restriction that has not been met.  
Examples of API restrictions: 
* Method can only be invoked by a subclass 
* Method can only be accessed from within the same library (defined by the Gradle library group id) .
* Method can only be accessed from tests. . 
You can add your own API restrictions with the @RestrictTo annotation.*
```

I am not sure this is a problem, because everything is working. 
But if this is a problem how can I solve it?

Thank you for your support.

My code is:

```
  public LiveData<List<Company>> listCompanys () {
    return new ComputableLiveData<List<Company>>() {
      @Override protected List<Company> compute() {
        List<Company> result= new ArrayList<>();
        //...
        return result;
      }
    }.getLiveData(); // this line gives error
  }
```

Comment: `ComputableLiveData` is an internal class: its not a part of public API, see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html) for subclasses of `LiveData` that you can use in your app

Answer (score 0):

It's something they did at IO to prevent people from using internal APIs they shouldn't be using.

`ComputableLiveData` is one of those classes.